# Remove extra comma in comma-delimited string

Tags: java, string

Suppose if i have this string

```
Result="INDIA,,USA,SA,NA,,PAK";
```

from this Result string how can i remove `,` (cComma) symbol if i have more than one comma i need to replace with sigle comma.How can i do this?

expected Result:

```
"INDIA,USA,SA,NA,PAK";
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show it!

Comment: User replaceAll(",,",",")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With replaceAll:

```
Result = Result.replaceAll(",{2,}", ",");
```

The `",{2,}"` is a regex, used to replace the comma character if it appears at least twice.

Comment: If i have 100 commos, then how can i remove those and replace with single , ?

Comment: @user3467244 - Yes; this answer and Kent's answer will take care of at least two commas

Comment: @user3467244 That's what `{2,}` is for. It means **at least twice**, so twice, 3 times, a hundred, a thousand, ...

Answer (score 2):

does this help?

```
Result = Result.replaceAll(",+", ",");
```

P.S, better follow the java naming convention, name the variable as `result` (small `r`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Result = Result.replaceAll(",,", ",")
```

Comment: Why are you replacing single-quotes when he wants commas replaced?

Comment: If i have 100 , then how can i remove those and replace with single , ?

Comment: @user3467244 look at my answer for that.